# How to add second value to same loop?

Tags: python, linux

Im writing script to compare today data and yesterdays data,Data in three list. today's data some times not available, here data not available.

S = ['abcd5934','abcd5935','abcd5936','abcd7154','abcd7155','abcd7156']

Yesterday - [(u'abcd7154', u'1'), (u'abcd7155', u'2'), (u'abcd7156', u'3')]

Today - []

So what i want to check yesterday list and today list with list S, is that is available in print S with that respective another value. EX -print out put 
abcd5934 Value not is yesterday  : Empty
abcd5935 Value not is yesterday  : Empty
abcd5936 Value not is yesterday  : Empty
abcd7154 Value is in yesterday : 1
abcd7155 Value is in yesterday : 2
abcd7156 Value is in yesterday : 3

```
if len(today) == 0:

               for server in S:

                        if server in yesterday:
                                print "YES "


                        else:
                                print "NO "
```

Can you help me to add second value to same loop ?

Comment: Could you be more clear with your question?

Comment: Sorry but my parser raised a syntax error. Could you rephrase all this so we might have a chance to understand the question ?

Comment: Agreed, clarifying will definitely help but if all you want to check is whether particular elements of S are among the first elements of the tuples within Yesterday you should go ahead and change your 3rd (or 5th, but those empty ones are redundant) line to `if server in [x[0] for x in Yesterday]:`.

Comment: S is a another list which use as constant list, other are list get from DB, it is changing day to day , I use S to get  value from today and tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come with the solution, Thanks for the every on who support me and encourage me.

```
S = ['abcd5934','abcd5935','abcd5936','abcd7154','abcd7155','abcd7156']

Yesterday = [(u'abcd7154', u'1'), (u'abcd7155', u'2'), (u'abcd7156', u'3')]

Today = []


y_servers = [srvr[0] for srvr in Yesterday]
value = [Yes[1] for Yes in Yesterday]
print y_servers
print value
v = 0
for srv in S:

    if srv in y_servers:
        print("YES, VALUE= %s") % v
    else:
        print("NO Value = Empty")
    v +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking something like this. Even though this is not correct answer for your question. But its the approach you're looking for.

```
if any( x in S for x in yesterday):
  print("Yes")
else:
  print("No")
```

Comment: yes but i have to print the particular value with this , something like 

YES - bcd7154 - 1

Answer (score 0):

You're question is really unclear, but @mtkilic's answer helped me understanding ... something.

It look like you want something like :

```
for server in S:
    for yesterday_1, yesterday_2 in yesterday:
        if server == yesterday_1:
            print "YES : " + str(yesterday_2)
        else:
            print "NO "
```

Answer (score 0):

@B. Barbieri, I think your code does the job but we probably don't need to print "NO" for each element of yesterday. I guess we might as well stop the iteration once we find a match.

```
for server in S:
    if server in [x[0] for x in yesterday]:
        print("YES: {}".format([x[1] for x in yesterday if x[0] == server][0]))
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Comment: actually this is sample code, Im using this logic to write in to the html, i have to show this was the value for abcd7154' = 1 for yesterday today there is no value for it, and yesterday abcd5935  does not had in the yesterday but it in today with value of 1, something like that i have to show in the htmls page